# Does drawing multiple cards count individually?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Say if I have the emblem of [Teferi, Hero of Dominaria](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTeferi%2c%20Hero%20of%20Dominaria%5d) (Whenever you draw a card, you may exile target permanent) out, and cast [Brainstorm](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBrainstorm%5d) (Draw three cards, then put two cards from your hand on top of your library in any order). How many times does the emblem trigger?

Answer (score 5):

> 120.2. Cards may only be drawn one at a time. If a player is instructed to draw multiple cards, that player performs that many individual card draws.

So [Brainstorm](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBrainstorm%5d) causes three card draws, and three triggers of Teferi's emblem, so you get to exile three permanents. Neat!